# Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy where the models are defined in different files?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm using SQLAlchemy for the first time and trying to define my models / schema. My only experience with ORM prior to this was with Rails and [ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Anyway, following SQLAlchemy's ORM Quick Start, this is the basic example they use (I have removed a few lines which are not relevant to my question):

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))

    addresses: Mapped[list["Address"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email_address: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user_account.id"))

    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="addresses")
```

My question is: is it possible to create two models in separate files (`user.py` and `address.py`), defining each model in its own file, and then import them and run a command like the following in order to instantiate the database:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: As long as they both inherit from the same `Base` and both files are imported at runtime, this is totally possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- what you are asking is both possible and is the standard way of creating SQLAlchemy Schemas.

The only gotcha is that you want all of your models to inherit from the same `DeclarativeBase`. This is essentially what registers them with SQLAlchemy and other plugins/tools like Alembic.

There are a few organization structures you can use, but a simple and common one is something like this:

```
- project_root
  - models
    + __init__.py
    + user.py
    + address.py
  - utils
  - scripts
```

In `models.__init__`, create and export your Base (I'd recommend giving it a slightly more specific name, such as `ModelBase`). Then in each of your model files, just import `ModelBase` and cut/paste your existing code.

Some projects enforce a single model per file. Others group related models together.

Since all of your models import and use a single `DeclaritiveBase`, you can call methods like `BaseModel.metadata.create_all()`. Just keep in mind you will still need to import those actual models somewhere.

An easy way to handle that is to import them inside of `models.__init__.py`. That way you will essentially load them whenever you import and use `ModelBase`.

```
# models.__init__.py
from .user import User
from .address import Address

class ModelBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

Comment: Wouldn't this generate a circular dependency?

Comment: I did try this solution, but I actually got an importError: cannot import name 'ModelBase' from partially initialized module 'lib' (most likely due to a circular import). Are you sure about your solution Brian?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to extend on [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75290599/10802163). When using an approach similar to his, I ran into an `ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelBase' from partially initialized module 'lib' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

I just made a really quick change that did remove this error, by simply switching the order of `ModelBase` declaration and models imports in `__init__.py`:

```py
# models.__init__.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class ModelBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

from .user import User
from .address import Address
```